# Callback problem error when testing learnyounode exercise 6 (Make It Modular)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

While testing exercise 6 of learnyounode (Make It Modular) my code is passing all of the tests but one and showing a TypeError: callback is not a function.

```
  ACTUAL                                 EXPECTED                
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

   "CHANGELOG.md"                      ==    "CHANGELOG.md"                     
   "LICENCE.md"                        ==    "LICENCE.md"                       
   "README.md"                         ==    "README.md"                        

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

 ✓ 

 Submission results match expected

Error
 ✓ 

 Additional module file exports a single function

 ✓ 

 Additional module file exports a function that takes 3 arguments

 ✓ 

 Additional module file handles errors properly

 ✓ 

 Additional module file handles callback argument

 ✓ 

 Additional module file returned two arguments on the callback function

 ✓ 

 Additional module file returned an Array as the second argument of the
 callback

data.dat
learnyounode.dat
w00t.dat
words.dat
 ✓ 

 Additional module file correctly handles '.'-prefixed extension

 ✗ 

 Your additional module file [mymodule.js] did not return an Array with the
 correct number of elements as the second argument of the callback

 # FAIL Your solution to MAKE IT MODULAR didn't pass. Try again!

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

mymodule.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');

function extFunc(directory, ext, callbackFunc) {
    fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error")
            return callbackFunc(err);
        }
        
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            if (path.extname(file) === ext) {
                console.log(file);
            };
        });
        callbackFunc(err, files);
    })
};

module.exports = extFunc;
```

make-it-modular.js

```
const extFunc = require('./mymodule');

const directory = process.argv[2];
const ext = '.' + process.argv[3];

extFunc(directory, ext);
```

I'd be hugely grateful if I could get some feedback on why the callback function in mymodule.js is throwing this error and causing me to ultimately fail the learnyounode test suite.

Comment: There's no `TypeError` or `callback` in your question. The only problem I see is a failed test because you're not filtering the files correctly/at all.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, I updated mymodule.js to include the filter and in make-it-modular.js correctly called extFunc() and used the forEach() method in there. Success!